# What class defaults for Improved Strength/Cat's Grace Spells for Psionicist?

Tags: spells, psionics, adnd-2e

In Spells & Magic, only four class categories – Priest, Warrior, Wizard, Rogue – are used for **defaults** for calculating how much Strength or Dexterity is gained when using these buffs. These class categories also determine Maximum.

The attributes Psionicists are good at are Wisdom, Constitution, and Intelligence, although the metabolic sciences are known to have high Dexterity & Strength users (Animal Affinity, Adrenalin Control, etc.)

Cat's grace/Dexterity dumps on Priests and boosts Rogues the most,
Improved Strength dumps on Wizards and improves Warriors the most.

Also, if there was a Wisdom variant, would Psionicists be the same table as Priests?

Answer (score 1):

### There is no official fallback class group

Pionicists form their own class group. They have their own group for nonweapon-proficiencies, for example, alongside rogue, warrior, wizard, and priest. And there is no guidance in *The Complete Psionics Handbook* what class group to fall back onto when other rules do not list Psionicists, so how to interpret features that only reference the four core groups but not Psionicists will be up to the DM.

That said, what could be a reasonable choice? While Complete Psionics goes on at length how Psionics is different from clerical or arcane magic (p. 7, "Is Psionics Magic?") to justify a different class category, when it comes to how it plays, it's pretty similar to magic ... for which reason later editions decided just use Psionics as a different way to cast spells<sup>1</sup>. Even second edition acknowledges in the *Planeswalker's Handbook* on page 91 how they play:

> **Psionicists are basically wizards**, as far as most planewalkers are concerned - although their highly trained minds are certainly worthy of respect in a place where the power of minds and beliefs can change the multiverse

In the multiclassing options available for Halflings and Dwaves (p. 8, *Complete Psionics Handbook*) both of which can be thieves, fighers or clerics, possible combinations are fighter/psionicist or thief/psionicist, but not cleric/psionicist suggesting that those might be too similar to make for an interesting combination. The XP progression is also closer to that of a cleric than that of a wizard, at least in the first 9 levels, where much of play happens.

I personally think that wizard might also be a reasonable option. It gives halflings and dwarves a way to play a class that can do a lot of what a wizard can do, with good options for control, transmutation, teleport and so on. The main outlier is that they have some healing prowess, which would be a priest's domain. Psionicists have a limited list of mostly simple weapons, similar to a wizard, and unlike clerics cannot wear heavy or metal armor, although they can have a shield. The hit dice (d6) are also half-way between wizard (d4) and cleric (d8).

In the end, your DM will have to decide what to do here (or, you yourself if you are the DM), but I think going with cleric or wizard would be most reasonable.

---

<sup>1</sup> While this is a rules-economic and reasonable approach, it also makes Psionics feel less special and distinct.

Comment: Proposed possibility?
Wis - always best: improved stat: d8+4/25 cap
Con - High d8-d6+4/23-25 cap
Int - High d6+4/23 cap
Str - Middle/High d6+4/23 cap
Dex - Middle/low d4+4/21 cap
Dump Stat: Cha - always worst d4+4/21 cap